# Is there a Java Minecraft function that gets the list of all players on the current server, like when you press TAB?

Tags: java, minecraft, minecraft-forge

I'm working on a Minecraft 1.8.9 client mod and want to be able to get a list of all the players on a server, the list that you get when you press TAB. Is there a function for that?

Answer (score 1):

```java
Minecraft.getMinecraft().getConnection().getPlayerInfoMap();
```

This will return a collection of `NetworkPlayerInfo` where you can `getDisplayName()` (name/nickname) or `getGameProfile()` from which you can `getName()` (name), `getId()` (UUID) and more. It will return null if there are no other network players; e.g. in a local world.